# WPF: data in DataTemplate not getting loaded when used with ContentControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datatemplate

I am using ContentControl with DataTemplate to load data but data not getting loaded.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:VesselInspectionSummaryViewModel}">                     
<StackPanel>                                  
<ContentControl Content="{Binding InternalInspections}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource  InternalInspectionSummaryDataTemplate}"  ></ContentControl>
</StackPanel>....
```

My concern with ContentControl which is inside DataTemplate, definition of InternalInspectionSummaryDataTemplate is as mentioned below.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="InternalInspectionSummaryDataTemplate" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding  Value}"   Style="{StaticResource   HomeDetailsTitleFontStyle}"  />
</DataTemplate>
```

But somehow I am not able to to display text for TextBlock which is a "Value".
Can anyone please help me out to get value for field textBlock.

Comment: `Value` is a member of `InternalInspections`? And `InternalInspections` is a member of `VesselInspectionSummaryViewModel`? Check the Output tab of Visual Studio, you should see the Binding error there and it could shed some light on your problem.

Comment: @almulo what you have understood is correct also I have checked Output tabl there is nothing significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finall I got the issue, it was not related with the xaml but in Viewmodel.
Previous code was.

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<InspectionUrgencyDetailViewModel> _externalInspections;
public ObservableCollection<InspectionUrgencyDetailViewModel> ExternalInspections { get; set; }

private readonly ObservableCollection<InspectionUrgencyDetailViewModel> _internalInspections;
public ObservableCollection<InspectionUrgencyDetailViewModel> InternalInspections { get; set; }
```

If you see properties does not corresponds to private variables so changed it to below.

```
        private ObservableCollection<InspectionUrgencyDetailViewModel> _externalInspections;
        public ObservableCollection<InspectionUrgencyDetailViewModel> ExternalInspections
        {
            get { return _externalInspections; }
            set { Set(() => ExternalInspections, ref _externalInspections, value); }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<InspectionUrgencyDetailViewModel> _internalInspections;
        public ObservableCollection<InspectionUrgencyDetailViewModel> InternalInspections
        {
            get { return _internalInspections; }
            set { Set(() => InternalInspections, ref _internalInspections, value); }
```